# Mongo_mapper limit results

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper, database

I have a query like this:

```
  @allJobs = Job.where(:merchant_id => session[:admin_id].to_s).sort(:start_date.desc).limit(100)
```

When I run .count on this I get:

```
 jobs count 1720
```

I expect to see :

```
 jobs count 100
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I try to run Job.all(query).limit(100) I get "undefined method limit for Array #foo"

It seems there is no way I can get the results to restrict to 100 records sorted in descending order by start_date!

UPDATE:

I cannot even do something simple like this:

```
@allJobs = Job.limit(100)
      Rails.logger.info("@allJobs count is " + @allJobs.count.to_s)
```

Console:

```
@allJobs count is 2080
```

.limit() is completely useless as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it seems logical to start my clauses with the where, and narrow them down further, or modify them… In MongoMapper, I find querying rigor is much more “loose” than say a SQL SELECT query that requires things in proper order… I would tend to write my queries in more or less this fashion:

```
ModelClass.where(some criteria).[sort | order | another where clause | fields | limit].[all | first | paginate]
```

In addition, it is important to note that MongoMapper returns a query and does not actually *perform* the query until you add something that needs the results. For example: `all`, `first`, `paginate`, `sort`, etc.

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > Structure.where(:address => /NJ/).count
 => 22 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > Structure.where(:address => /NJ/).limit(2).count
 => 22 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > Structure.where(:address => /NJ/).limit(2).all.count
 => 2
```

More details here: http://technicaldebt.com/mongomapper-query-review/ and for the underlying Plucky query syntax, here: https://github.com/mongomapper/plucky

Comment: I'm giving Jon the answer because it made more sense to me than the answer below - though now that I have Jon's answer, reading below does make sense.  At first glance though, I couldn't get it until this wording and example code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `count()` and `limit()` for a MongoDB cursor do not interact the way you are anticipating.

By default a [`cursor.count()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/) shows the number of documents referenced by a cursor, but it doesn't take into account the limit.

The [`cursor.limit()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) option determines the maximum number of documents that will be returned by the cursor.

If you are querying via the `mongo` shell you can use `cursor.count(true)` to have `count()` respect the limit.  I suspect this may work in MongoMapper as well.

I would also try your `where()` query with a smaller restriction like `limit(5)` so you can more easily confirm the limit is working as expected when you print the results.

> If I try to run Job.all(query).limit(100) I get "undefined method limit for Array #foo"

MongoMapper's [`all()`](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html#all) returns the results as an array, so it is too late to apply the limit for the cursor since the documents are already fetched.