# How do I set $maxScan?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I have a query like so.

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.BSONFormats._
def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("persons")
val q = Json.obj("foo" -> "bar")
collection.find(q).cursor[JsObject].collect[Seq](500)
```

How do I set [$maxScan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxScan/) on this query?

Comment: I tried val q = Json.obj("foo"->"bar", "$maxScan"->100) but that did not work.

Comment: Also tried `val q = Json.obj("$query" -> Json.obj("foo"->"bar"), "$maxScan" -> 100)` which does not work either.

Comment: Are you sure you want to set `$maxScan` (limit on documents scanned)? This is different from the [`cursor.limit()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) value, which is the number of documents that will be returned. For a comparison of usage, you could have a look at this recent question on StackOverflow: [Mongo_mapper limit results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778135/).

Comment: @Stennie, Yes I am sure.  Limit does not prevent a full collection scan if the query parameters are particularly limiting.  I am fully aware that $maxScan will cause indeterminate results.